Should I use leveling clips for 3 x 18 tile?
I plan on tiling my bathroom walls with 3 x 18 (2.875" x 17.625") tile.  I've heard you should use leveling clips for 12 x 12 or larger tile.  I'm larger than this limit in one dimension, but not the other, so I wasn't sure if my tiles are considered "larger" than 12 x 12.

Yes.   They will make the install look more professional, and will force you to redo the thinset behind some tiles right away.    In fact if you are doing larger tiles and you have to ask if you should use leveling clips, the answer is always yes.    I have 4-5 tilers and they have tiled for 20+ years a piece.   Two of them still use leveling clips.
